# Autodesk Simple Viewer - "Could not list models. "

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to implement the code example in this repo:

https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-dotnet

While launching in debugging mode, I get an error in the AuthController.cs says:

> Could not list models. See the console for more details

I didn't make any significant changes to the original code, I only changed the env vars (client id, secret etc..)

The error is on the below function:

```
async function setupModelSelection(viewer, selectedUrn) {
    const dropdown = document.getElementById('models');
    dropdown.innerHTML = '';
    try {
        const resp = await fetch('/api/models');
        if (!resp.ok) {
            throw new Error(await resp.text());
        }
        const models = await resp.json();
        dropdown.innerHTML = models.map(model => `<option value=${model.urn} ${model.urn === selectedUrn ? 'selected' : ''}>${model.name}</option>`).join('\n');
        dropdown.onchange = () => onModelSelected(viewer, dropdown.value);
        if (dropdown.value) {
            onModelSelected(viewer, dropdown.value);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert('Could not list models. See the console for more details.');
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I get an access token so my client id and secret are probably correct, I also added the app to the cloud hub, what could be the problem, why the app can't find the projects in the hub?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the tutorials where this repo come from [APS Tutorials](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/simple-viewer/) ? I think this repo is not made to work with BIM360 or ACC hubs, but only with OSS (buckets / objects). The next tutorial show how to get models from hubs [APS Hubs Browser DotNet](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-hubs-browser-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

I can only repeat what [AlexAR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9365707/alexar) said - the given sample is not for accessing files from user hubs like ACC/BIM 360 Docs - for that follow this: https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/

To address the specific error. One way I can reproduce that is if I set the `APS_BUCKET` variable to something simple that has likely been used by someone else already, e.g. "mybucket", and so I'll get an error when trying to access the files in it, since it's **not my bucket**. Bucket names need to be **globally unique**. If you don't want to come up with a unique name yourself, then just do not declare the `APS_BUCKET` environment variable and the sample will generate a bucket name for you based on the **client id** of your app.